# What does an exponent of a differential form mean?

Tags: differential-forms, exterior-algebra

I know that the wedge product is alternative, $\omega \wedge \omega =0$, but I still see people talking about $\omega^{\wedge n}$ like when the power of a symplectic form is considered as the volume form. I assume that this volume form is meant to be non zero for higher dimensions but I can’t see how. Is this just some weird short hand for something else?

Comment: Isn't this just $\omega^{\wedge n}=\omega\wedge \cdots \wedge \omega$?

Comment: $\omega^n = \omega \wedge .....\wedge \omega$ (n times)

Comment: Is $\omega$ a vector or a space?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If $\omega$ is a $p$-form and $\eta$ is a $q$-form, then $\omega\wedge\eta = (-1)^{pq}\eta\wedge\omega$. In particular, if $p$ is odd, then $\omega\wedge\omega = -\omega\wedge\omega$ and hence $\omega\wedge\omega = 0$. However, if $p$ is even, then $\omega\wedge\omega$ need not be zero. For example, if $\omega$ is a symplectic form on a $2n$-dimensional manifold with $n > 1$, then $\omega\wedge\omega \neq 0$; in fact, $\omega^n = \underbrace{\omega\wedge\dots\wedge\omega}_{n\ \text{times}}$ is non-zero.

For an explicit example, consider $\omega = dx^1\wedge dx^2 + dx^3\wedge dx^4$ on $\mathbb{R}^4$. Note that

$$\omega\wedge\omega = 2dx^1\wedge dx^2\wedge dx^3\wedge dx^4 \neq 0.$$

Comment: How is $\omega ^{\wedge 2}=2\omega$? When squaring a form, you can always use anti symmetry to rearrange the product in such a way to get $dx^1 \wedge dx^1$ which is $0$

Comment: I never said $\omega^{\wedge 2} = 2\omega$. Note that in the example $\omega = dx^1\wedge dx^2 \color{red}{+} dx^3\wedge dx^4$, not $dx^1\wedge dx^2\wedge dx^3\wedge dx^4$.

Comment: The square of a 1-form is always zero. The square of a decomposable form is always zero. Otherwise, the square of a differential form is not necessarily zero.